# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with console app

Tags: objective-c, c, exc-bad-access

I'm attempting to learn Objective C (and C along with it), and writing an interactive console app.  My background is in Java, and many of the differences in Objective C are still unintuitive to me.
I've written the following method:

```
-(void)start {
    [self startMenu]; // calls a method that prints the menu options
    char selectedOption = '\0'; // instantiating selectedOption
    char w = 'w';
    char n = 'n';
    char b = 'b';
    bool validOption = NO;
    while(!validOption) {
        scanf("%c", selectedOption);
        if(selectedOption == w) {
            [self setWinningScore];
        } else if(selectedOption == n) {
            [self setName];
        } else if(selectedOption == b) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("'%s' is not a valid option.\n", selectedOption);
        }

    }
}
```

But whenever it runs, it gives a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when it reaches the line `scanf("%c", *selectedOption);`.

I've googled this error.  I found **[this article](http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access)** by Lou Franco, but I'm still at a loss as to what I can do.

**EDIT**

As Bryan pointed out, I was misusing pointers and pointer dereferences.  Unfortunately, after cleaning my code, it still gives the same error.

Comment: The `scanf` issue is pure C, not Objective-C.

Comment: True, good point.  Edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

please learn what is pointer first.

your problem is trying to dereference invalid pointer.

```
-(void)start {
    [self startMenu]; // calls a method that prints the menu options
    char selectedOption = '\0';
    char w = 'w';
    char n = 'n';
    char b = 'b';
    bool validOption = NO;
    while(!validOption) {
        scanf("%c", &selectedOption);
        if(selectedOption == w) {
            [self setWinningScore];
        } else if(selectedOption == n) {
            [self setName];
        } else if(selectedOption == b) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("'%c' is not a valid option.\n", selectedOption);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I just changed my code according to your answer.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the exact same error in the exact same place.  Also, I have read and re-read what pointer means.  I kind of get it, but my understanding is still a bit shaky due to my Java background.  I don't think that should disqualify me from asking this question after spending an hour trying to solve it.

Comment: @TJamesBoone: So, just to confirm, the line now reads `scanf("%c", &selectedOption);` — **with the ampersand** — and you're still getting the error?

Comment: @Chuck Yes.  I even tried both.  With or without the ampersand, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @TJamesBoone have you tried clean rebuild? and does debugger tell you any error message? which line?

Comment: @Chuck  Huh!  That did it!  :p  Thanks.  I guess I should accept Bryan Chen's answer.

Comment: Actually, I think what was throwing me off, was I was now getting the error on the bottom line, in the else statement, since that also needs an ampersand.  I noticed that after I cleaned it and changed it.  Other than that, Bryan's answer is perfect.

Comment: @TJamesBoone: The printf() should not need an ampersand. Something is going really weird if it's working with an ampersand there.

Comment: @Chuck I will admit, my program is now behaving in unexpected ways.  But it's no longer giving me that error, so I was thinking it's now a separate problem.  But apparently not.  I'll need to find some explanation on pointers that isn't so convoluted to my Java brain.